# main() having read-only access to edited values inside continuously running threads - C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, mutex, shared-memory

I create several pthreads inside the main() function of my C++ program. Once the threads are created each of them are responsible to create a UDP socket and listen on specific port. Based on the data arriving on each port, the threads modify global variables which are at the same time going to be read by the main function inside a loop. The question is if I can use mutex to follow the same procedure inside the main function, or the main function is itself consuming a lot of resources that the better way is to make another thread responsible to read the modified data? (and ofcourse in this new thread I have the option of using mutex) 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using a mutex is not an "option", it's a *must* if you want to avoid data-races.

Comment: And what use would another thread be? What would it do differently than the main thread? What would then the main thread do?

Comment: You should protect the global data in each thread that is using it with a mutex.

Comment: I suggest to attach your source code and replacing detailed statements with a comment.

Comment: Basically the main is going to read 4 values edited by 4 threads and then after some processing write only one value inside a text file. So thats exactly what the new thread is going to do.So I should also implement mutex on the main side that avoids the 4 thread to write while he is reading. But the question is if the main() function has some privileges to the created threads. Having a new thread means that the main function is only responsible for creating all the threads and thats it. no more processing...

Comment: @AliNouri You still either need a mutex and/or atomic variables.  All threads are the same so your new thread still needs synchronised access to the variables being updated.

Comment: Consider using a [condition variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) so that the relevant thread is woken up when there is something to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no significant difference between the "main" thread and other threads it creates.  Once the additional threads are created, they all have the same access rights and memory mappings.